# how to delete table row on right click

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtablewidget

I am trying to make it so you can right click on a row in the table widget and delete it. I am unable to find a working example of this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my updated code to better visualize:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) {
    if (obj == ui->tableWidgetOther->viewport() ) {
        QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
        if (mouseEvent->button() == Qt::RightButton) {
            QTableWidgetItem *cell = ui->tableWidgetOther->currentItem();
            int row = cell->row();
            ui->tableWidgetOther->removeRow(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a [`QTableWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html) with Qt Designer and set the rows and columns not necessarily every grid has a [`QTableWidgetItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html) associated so it is not best to use [`currentItem()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#currentItem).

So instead of using a [`QTableWidgetItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html) you should use a [`QModelIndex`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html) using the [`indexAt()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#indexAt) method and the position of the event.

As the requirement is the right click so it is not correct to use the [`cellClicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#cellClicked) signal. In this case I will use an [`eventFilter()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#eventFilter).

```
ui->tableWidget->viewport()->installEventFilter(this);
```

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) { 
    if (obj == ui->tableWidget->viewport() and 
        event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress) {
        QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
        if (mouseEvent->button() == Qt::RightButton) {
            QModelIndex ix = ui->tableWidget->indexAt(mouseEvent->pos());
            if(ix.isValid())
                ui->tableWidget->removeRow(ix.row());
        }
    }
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

If you want to build your own [`QTableWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html) then the same logic is implemented in the [`mousePressEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#mousePressEvent) method:

```cpp
void TableWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->buttons() == Qt::RightButton){
        QPoint p = viewport()->mapFromGlobal(mapToGlobal(event->pos()));
        QModelIndex ix = indexAt(p);
        if(ix.isValid())
            removeRow(ix.row());
    }
    QTableWidget::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Im usually coding in C# not C++ so you made this easy to understand and it now works when I right click on the row

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking to detect a right-click, one approach is to install an event filter over your QTableWidget's viewport:

```
ui->tableWidget->viewport()->installEventFilter(this)
```

You could do this in your mainWindow's constructor.

This event filter allows us to see if a mousePressEvent is occurring over our table, which we can then retrieve the row from. That means we need an eventFilter method to process our mousePressEvent and make sure it is on our tableWidget:

```
mainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) { 
    if (obj == ui->tableWidget->viewport() ) {
        QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event)
        if (mouseEvent->button() == Qt::RightButton) {
            QTableWidgetItem *cell = ui->TableWidget->currentItem();
            int row = cell->row()
            ui->tableWidget->removeRow(row)
        }
    }
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Let us know if that worked!

Comment: It gives me a crash when I click on the table and im told in editor "Control reaches end of non void function" I added my edited code to the post so you can better visualize how I typeed it out.

Comment: I forgot to add the return in the eventFilter code. Take a look at it again if one of the other answers didn't already work!

Comment: @RakeebHossain Your code also has another error, you are assuming that the only event is the QMouseEvent, if another event like the FocusEvent is sent before that then mouseEvent will generate an error, if you check my implementation I do a verification using the type() of the event .

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the warning/error "Control reaches end of non void function" is raised because you did not return anything while `eventFilter()` is supposed to return a `bool`.

Secondly, why don't you use directly [`mousePressEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#mousePressEvent) or [`mouseReleaseEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#mouseReleaseEvent) ?

I think you should override one of these methods of your `tableWidgetOther` object and do the remove task from here.

It could look like:

```
void TableWidgetOther::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    if(event->buttons() == Qt::RightButton)
    {
        // TODO: remove the current cell (or do whatever you want).
    }
}
```

I assumed here that you have your `tableWidgetOther` object as an instance of a `TableWidgetOther` class that inherits `QTableWidget` (only for the example).

I think this is the simplest solution if you want to handle mouse events (only my opinion).

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Im still new to QT, I was told  that the void TableWidgetOther is an undeclared identifier? How do I resolve that error

Comment: @SebastianShearer Yes because you don't have any TableWidgetOther class. This was about creating a class that inherits `QTableWidget` not directly a QTableWidget. But the accepted answers is much more complete :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cellClicked(int, int)` signal and connect it to slot which would delete the row. For example:

```
void MainWindow::deleteRow(int row, int column)
{
    removeRow(row);
    Q_UNUSED(column)
}

connect(ui->tableWidget, SIGNAL(cellClicked(int, int)), this, SLOT(deleteRow(int, int)));
```

**EDIT:**

Using new connection syntax it would look like this:

```
connect(ui->tableWidget, &QTableWidget::cellClicked, this, &MainWindow::deleteRow);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent suggestion ! But I think you shouldn't use the old connection syntax with the SIGNAL and SLOT macros. You should have written: `connect(ui->tableWidget, &QTableWidget::cellClicked, this, &MainWindow::deleteRow);` (assuming the `tableWidget` is a `QTableWidget`).

Comment: I made a mistake, I forgot that the OP want to use the right-click, so `cellClicked()` cannot do the job, as @eyllanesc mentioned.